# In how many ways we can divide a set $A$ which has $km$ elements into $m$, $k$-element sets such that all of the sets are disjoint?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $A$ be a set with $km$ elements ($k,m \in \mathbb N$). In how many ways we can divide the set $A$ into $m$, $k$-element sets such that all of the sets are disjoint?

In case one has difficulty to understand the question statement, here is an example:
Let $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. We want to divide the set into $3$, $2$-element sets such that the new sets are disjoint. Here is one such combination: $A=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$. In this case, $A=\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$, $A=\{\{2,1\},\{4,3\},\{5,6\}\}$, $A=\{\{3,4\},\{1,2\},\{5,6\}\}$ etc. are all the same. That means the order of the sets doesn't matter.

As the order of the sets doesn't matter, we can choose the first set in $\binom {km} {k}$. After the first choice, there are $(km-k)$ elements left. So, we can have the second choice in $\binom {km-k} {k}$ ways and so on. So, I think the answer would be $\binom {km} {k} \cdot \binom {km-k} {k} \cdots \binom 0 k=\frac {(km)!} {k!(km-k)!} \cdot \frac {(km-k)!} {k!(km-2k)!} \cdots =\frac {(km)!} {(k!)^m}$.

Is this correct?
(This may be easy for most of the users here. But as I am not good at counting problems and I am also confused in these kind of problems, I posted this to remove my confusion.)

Comment: No, it is not quite correct. As the order of the sets does not matter, you need to divide your answer by $m!$ to allow for this. For example, in your example with $m=3$ and $n=2$ your formula gives 9o but the correct answer is 15.

Comment: That's a good start, but not quite correct yet. You are counting each combination $m!$ times in your result, since you make an arbitrary choice which $k$ elements form the _first_, _second_ set and so on, but in your combinations, there is no order of the subsets. Thus, you should divide your final result by $m!$.

Comment: Just don't use $\binom 0 k$ as that doesn't make any sense :) Just stop at $\binom k k$